# How to print string even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> Given a string S of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1 print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 2
>
> Hacker
>
> Rank
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> Hce akr
>
> Rn ak
> ```

I tried it in VScode and worked but when i submit it in HackerRank they give me the output like this

```
2Hce

ak 

akrRn
```

there is a number (2) involved but i don't know what to do with it. here's the code

```
function processData(input) {

  let strToArr = input.split('');
  let evenArr = [];
  let oddArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < strToArr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      evenArr.push(strToArr[i]);
    } else if(i%2===1){
      oddArr.push(strToArr[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(evenArr.join('') + ' ' + oddArr.join(''));
}

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);
});
```

Comment: See the full hackerrank input specification. You're given a number of lines in the first input line, and then that many input lines, *for each* of which you should apply the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Using `split()` with the separator,`'\n'`, puts the sub-strings in newlines.
And the integer, in this case `2` can be omitted from string copy using `slice(1)`, the `1`for where the slicing starts.
Using `forEach()`  to execute for every sub-string the following:

1. create variables even and odd
2. `for` to loop through each character(element) of each sub-string
3. if statement to check if index(`i`) is even or odd
4. if is index `even` add `element` to even string
5. else add to `odd` string

   ```
   function processData(input){
   //Enter your code here
   //split() input str into new line and exctract(omitting the integer)
   let strCopy = input.split("\n").slice(1);
   //forEach element of the split input
   strCopy.forEach(element => {
    let even = "",
    let odd = "";
    //loop through to find the even and odd 
    for(let i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
     if(i % 2 === 0){
      even += element[i];
     }else {
      odd += element[i];
     }
    }
    console.log(`${even} ${odd}`);
   });
   }
   ```

Comment: You should add explanation how and why this solves the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Day 6 Let’s Review Hackerrank Solution | 30 Days of Code: C#

```
int T=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] str=new string[T];
        for(int i=0;i<str.Length;++i)
        {
            str[i]=Console.ReadLine();
        } 
     string odd="",even="";
    for(int i=0;i<str.Length;++i)
        {
         char[] ch=str[i].ToCharArray();
         for(int k=0;k<ch.Length;++k)
         {
             if(k%2==0)
             even+=ch[k];
             else
             odd+=ch[k];
             
         }    
         Console.WriteLine(even+" "+odd);
         even="";
         odd="";
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Index Shuffle
function indexShuf(str) {
    let newstr = str.split('');
    let newarry =[];
    let newarry1 =[];
    //return newstr;
    for(i=0 ; i<newstr.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 === 0) {
            newarry.push(newstr[i])
        }else {
            newarry1.push(newstr[i])
        }
    }return newarry.concat(newarry1).join('')
}
console.log(indexShuf("mayvcvcbe"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Day 6 Let’s Review Hackerrank Solution | 30 Days of Code: Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N= scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    
    for(int j=0; j<N;j++) {
        String S = scanner.next();
       
        char[] arr= S.toCharArray();
        String odd="";
        String even="";
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
        { 
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                even+=arr[i];
            }
            else
            {
                odd+=arr[i];
            }
       }
       System.out.println(even + " " + odd);
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```